# Поиск файлов с совпадающей частью имени и выбор последнего по дате

Tags: linux, bash, find

Прошу помощи  коллег.
Пытаюсь найти последние бекапы  по имени в подпапках, разница во времени между бекапами всегда разная.

```
find /backup/MSSQL/ -type f \( -name  "*HUB_backup*[0-9].bak" -o -name "*ERP_backup*[0-9].bak" \) -not -path "*/Differentional_backup/*" -mtime 0
```

данный код помагал брать последний файл за сутки.
Но теперь за сутки бекапов два.

Comment: попробуйте допишисать в конце вашей команды `-printf '%p;%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT\n' | sort -t';' -k2,2 | tail -n 1`

Comment: Это уже результат, спасибо.
Но я не уточнил, ваша команда дает самый последний файл из всех, а мне необходимо что б последний который соответствует каждому файлу.

Comment: *последний который соответствует каждому файлу* — расшифруйте, пожалуйста, что вы имеете ввиду. прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]. лучше не на словах а на примере.

Comment: Для группы файлов, попробуйте вот так добавить `-printf '%p;%Ts\n' | sort -r -t';' -k2,2 | sort -t'.' -k1,1 -u` и проверьте результат, если он не такой как ожидается, дополните вопрос названиями файлов и путей к ним

Comment: мой код возвращает список файлов за последний день, это по два одинаковых файла, мне нужно получать именно последний файл с этой пары.

Comment: В системе не может быть двух одинаковых файлов (исключение -- слои в overlayfs, но это не ваш случай).

Comment: Да, вы правы. Сейчас приведу пример.
/backup/MSSQL/Prod_ERP/Prod_ERP_backup_2020_07_16_233001_1306595.bak
/backup/MSSQL/Prod_ERP/Prod_ERP_backup_2020_07_17_004458_5815698.bak
/backup/MSSQL/HUB/HUB_backup_2020_07_16_233001_6018426.bak
Это мой вывод скрипта, мне же необходимо получить только 
/backup/MSSQL/HUB/HUB_backup_2020_07_16_233001_6018426.bak
/backup/MSSQL/Prod_ERP/Prod_ERP_backup_2020_07_17_004458_5815698.bak